# Как реализовать подобное?

Tags: java, android

Есть множественный выбор в приложении android. Нужно, чтобы программа выдавала среднее арифметическое выбранных пользователем позиций.

В первом активити

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

Button button_1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    button_1.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Во втором активити нужно присвоить переменную типа int ( напр. Uruguay - 3444000. Paraguay - 6725000, и т.д.) элементам списка

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] countries = { "Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", "Peru", "Mexico"};
Button button2

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView countriesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.countriesList);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);

    countriesList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

В общем, нужно рассчитать среднее арифметическое населения стран посредством нажатия button2 (Среднее арифметическое должно отображаться в следующем активити)

Список со странами отображается во втором активити с возможностью множественного выбора. А вот среднее арифметическое после выбора стран, отображается  втретьем активити

Comment: а можно по подробнее, что за выбор? какого типа список? какой адаптер? код напишите в вопросе. Ваш вопрос слишком общий

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос [минимальный воспроизводимый пример проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Сложить и поделить на количество.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо сложить значение всех элементов, поделить на их количество и выдать результат. Каков вопрос, таков ответ.